# Google Nexus 7 will not draw a larg bitmap, but acer tablet does it fine

Tags: android

I'm creating a puzzle app, that has 20 puzzles.  I made a bitmap that contains a image (255,by 255) of each puzzle, so it is 300 by 7680 (20*256*128-space in between).  I would change the starting point the bitmap is drwn on when a user drags his fingure over it.
This worked fine on my acer tablet and vergin phone, but the slider bitmap did not get drawn when i tried it on a nexus7 (which surprise me becouse my other 2 devices are outdated).

After playimg around with it, it seemed like nexus7 would not draw the bitmap if it was larger then a width of 2000.

Is there a way to fix this, or another way to allow useres to have a scroll with images of all the puzzles?

Comment: are you sure the bitmap is not drawn, or just not visible enough to be seen because nexus7 is a high dpi device. If you draw 1px, that is.

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005070/glsurfaceview-displaying-black-on-nexus-7-with-android-4-2

Comment: How many puzzle images do you want on the screen at any one time?